# IntelliJ repeatedly forgets that target src_managed is a source directory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2017.1 Ultimate edition. I am working on a scala project where I generate some code using SBT.

The code is copied into target/scala-2.11/src_managed folder.

Time and again, my compilation fails and I see that IntelliJ has forgotten that src_managed is a source dir

[image]

If i right click on the src_managed folder and say mark directory as source root then compilation succeeds. But its very irritating that IntelliJ forgets time and again, that this is a source directory.

Comment: IntelliJ should be able to follow the SBT build settings - did you add that folder as a source root in SBT ([like so](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory))?

Comment: like this? `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ / "target" / "scala-2.11" / "src_managed"),` I am not sure where does the baseDirectory start.

Comment: Not sure either :) actually, this might not be the best approach (that same section warns not to use this for generated code, and refers to http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html which might be more suitable) - I'm afraid that's as far as my SBT knowledge goes, hope these links might assist.

Comment: we have the same problem but it occurs only when you re-load the build.sbt (That's when IDEA generates the .iml file)

Comment: yes. I find that I have to mark the src_managed as a source file every time I change my build.sbt file. and this is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when you add `"main"` to the source path and it creates the sources in `src_managed/main` then Intellj picks it up:

```
.settings(
  (sourceGenerators in Compile) += (codeGen in Compile),
  (codeGen in Compile) := {
    val r = (runner in Compile).value
    val s = streams.value.log
    // This is [basedir]/target/scala-2.11/src_managed
    val sourcePath = sourceManaged.value
    val classPath = (fullClasspath in Test in `generator`).value.map(_.data)

    // This is [basedir]/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main
    val fileDir = new File(sourcePath, "main").getAbsoluteFile
    r.run(
     "com.github.integration.CodeGeneratorRunner",
      classPath, Seq(fileDir.getAbsolutePath), s
    )
  )
)
```

... and then intellj picks it up!

[image: Intellij Picks It Up]

I don't know how, I don't know why but it does. SBT works either way. Maybe there's some SBT convention we don't know about, maybe there's a bug with Intellij.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Just generate the files in `src_managed/main/` instead of in `src_managed/`.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this question as I had the same problem. Though this question is old, I'll answer with my solution for others that may have the same problem.

Add the directory as managed source directory in your build.sbt:

```
Compile / managedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "target/scala-2.13/src_managed"

// or if you have your scala version in a value/variable
lazy val scalaVersion = "2.13.3"
Compile / managedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / s"target/scala-${"""[\d]*[\.][\d]*""".r.findFirstIn(scalaVersion).get}/src_managed"
```